# My client can't read my server's response

Tags: java, client-server

This is my code for my server

```
    String request=di.readLine();
    System.out.print(request);

    switch (request){
        case "/login":                
         dout.writeBytes(request);
    }
```

This is for my client

```
String command = "/login \r\n";
       try{
       Socket s = new Socket ("localhost",8000);
       DataInputStream di = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
       DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());


       dout.writeBytes(command);
       System.out.println(di.readLine());

       }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("Log in error");
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

The server can get my command but my client can't read my server's response
I already try it in my telnet and it works. I think the problem is in my client program code

Comment: Flush the output stream.

Comment: @user3194331 .flush()

Comment: in my client or server ?

Comment: still nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

readLine() removes the line terminator, so when you send the result back to be read by a readLine() at the peer there is no line terminator, so the peer's readLine() blocks forever waiting for it.

Answer (score -1):

DataInputStream's readLine method is deprecated - don't use it.

Replace it with:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Put a call to .flush() when you want to send stuff. The output streams are buffered and will only send their data once the buffer is full or when you call flush(), or when the stream is closed.

Comment: Does it affects my serve's outputs when my server is with thread?

Comment: Do not understand question.

Comment: i already solved the problem thanks for helping me I placed \r\n in my server's ouputstream and i already received the repsonse of the server

Comment: Using deprecated methods does not cause this problem.